# Find distinct set of values using Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, distinct-values

I want to find the distinct list of values from a collection of certain fields across a number of tables in MS Access. However, my VBA code only returns the first value from every field (and not the full collection of distinct values in each field). Please see below:

```
Sub GetDistinctValues()

    Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Fields_To_Examine")

    Do While Not rs.EOF
    For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs

        If tbl.Name = rs("Table_Name") Then
        Debug.Print tbl.Name

            For Each fld In tbl.Fields
                If fld.Name = rs("Field_Name") Then
                Debug.Print fld.Name

                    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT " & tbl.Name & ".Source_System, " & tbl.Name & "." & fld.Name & " FROM " & tbl.Name)
                    Debug.Print rs1(0), rs1(1)

                    rs.MoveNext

                End If
            Next
         End If
    Next
    Loop

    rs.Close
    rs1.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rs1 = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

MoveNext is inside the field loop, so:

```
For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs

    If tbl.Name = rs("Table_Name") Then
    Debug.Print tbl.Name

        For Each fld In tbl.Fields
            If fld.Name = rs("Field_Name") Then
            Debug.Print fld.Name

                Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT " & tbl.Name & ".Source_System, " & tbl.Name & "." & fld.Name & " FROM " & tbl.Name)
                Debug.Print rs1(0), rs1(1)

            End If
        Next
     End If
Next
rs.MoveNext
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Gustav. However, I moved the rs.movenext to where you suggest but it still returns just the 1st value in each field?

Comment: Yes. I don't know what you are trying to do, but for each fld you just open rs1 but don't loop it, so it will never move.